# Consultas Select DB2

Tags: sql, db2

Buenos días,

Realizando una consulta en mi Base de Datos DB2, notamos algo curioso.  Al realizar la consulta a una Tabla dependiendo de la condición where, me despliega los datos.

```
SELECT NOMBRE    
  FROM X    
 WHERE NOMBRE = 'aaa '
```

Resultado: "aaa_" --> "_" representa espacios en blanco

```
SELECT NOMBRE
  FROM X
 WHERE NOMBRE = 'aaa      '
```

Resultado: "aaa______" --> "_" representa espacios en blanco

El valor devuelto es la misma fila (el mismo id) pero dependiendo del Where que realice, me muestra un resultado distinto del campo especificado.

No debería de ser estricto a la hora de ser un igual en la condición.?

--

Todo esto surgio, ya que estabamos recopilando que filas de varias tabla poseian espacios en blanco de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLA
WHERE COLUMNA LIKE '% %';
```

Sin embargo notamos que unos valores salian en una tabla y su correlación en otra tabla no aparecía utilizando el sql anterior.

Gracias,

Comment: Asumo que `NOMBRE` es un varchar. En ese caso, db2 (y varios otros motores de bases de datos) ignoran los espacios al final del texto

Comment: Esto según el estándar ANSI sobre cómo tratar los espacios en blanco a la derecha del texto ("trailing spaces")

Comment: Correcto el Tipo de Dato es un Varchar. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

En este [enlace](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/es/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0008479.html) creo que se aclara tu duda:

> **Comparaciones de serie de caracteres y serie gráfica**
>
> Las series de caracteres se comparan de acuerdo con el orden de clasificación especificado cuando se ha creado la base de datos,
>   excepto aquellos con un atributo FOR BIT DATA, que siempre se comparan
>   de acuerdo con sus valores de bits.
>
> ***Cuando se comparan series de caracteres de longitud desigual, la comparación se efectúa utilizando una copia lógica de la serie más
>   corta, rellenada por el lado derecho con espacios en blanco para
>   alargar dicha serie y alcanzar de esta manera la serie más larga.*** Esta
>   extensión lógica se realiza para todas las series de caracteres,
>   incluidas las que tienen el distintivo FOR BIT DATA.